# how to remove videojs's seekbar click event?

Tags: video.js

I just want to keep the drag event of seekbar, and I don't want users to click on it to adjust the video schedule.

I've tried to do this:

```js
this.player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.disable()
this.player.controlBar.progressControl.seekBar.handleClick = () => {}
```

But none of this is helpful.

Please help me. I've tried my best.

Answer (score 2):

```js
myPlayer.controlBar.progressControl.disable();
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using only CSS, putting these 3 lines in your html seems to solve it:

```
<style> 
.video-js  .vjs-progress-holder  .vjs-play-progress { display: none; }
</style>
```

Comment: sorry i don't want to hide it ,i only want to remove it's click event

Comment: If you try it, you;ll see that it does NOT hide the whole bar...only hides the thumb-slider that allows manual movement...hovering on the bar still shows time values on the bar.